# Check an array whether sum(x_0, x_1...x_k) == sum(x_k+1,..x_n) are equal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to implement to an algorithm to solve following problem in Haskell:

Given an array, check whether sum(x_0, x_1...x_k) == sum(x_k+1,...,x_n)

If the array is have NO element, then the sum is zero
[image]

1:

```
arr = [1]
sum([]) = 0
sum([1]) = 1
sum([]) != sum([1])
there is no such k 
return False
```

2:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
sum([1,2]) == sum([3])
there is such k
return True
```

Here is my current implementation so far:

```
checkSum::[Int]->Int->Bool
checkSum []  _ = True
checkSum [x] _ = x    == 0
checkSum l inx | sum(take inx l) == sum(drop inx l) = True
               | inx <= length l = checkSum l (inx+1)
               | otherwise       = False
```

It works, but I need to change function prototype as following:

```
checkSum::[Int]->Bool
.....
```

Does anyone know how to implement the new function without passing index to the function?

Comment: `\xs -> any (checkSum xs) [0 .. length xs - 1]`

Comment: Neither the textual specification of `sum(x_0, x_1...x_k) == sum(x_k+1,...,x_n)` or the diagram specification are clear to me. Based on reading the examples, I think the missing piece for the text specification is simply a quantifier, i.e. for some integer list `x` determine `∃k::Int. sum[x₀,…,xₖ] == sum[xₖ,…,xₙ]`.

Comment: FWIW, it was clear to me without a quantifier. Although I would recommend: *Check if a list can be split at some index into two halves with equal sums.*

Answer (score 3):

This function comes up a surprising amount:

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

splits :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Example usage:

```
ghci> splits [1,2,3]
[([],[1,2,3]),([1],[2,3]),([1,2],[3]),([1,2,3],[])]
```

You might also be interested in the [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) function.

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint, this sucks. karakfa's approach is fussier, but asymptotically more efficient.

Comment: Though due to the simplicity of this solution it is more obviously correct, and correctness is more important. For an efficient implementation we do want to exploit, from a monoid homomorphism with length, that `length xs + length ys == length (xs ++ ys)`. [Mauris](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34534073/260584) has a good solution for this which uses `scanl`.

Answer (score 3):

A more primitive approach

```
checkSum :: [Int] -> Bool
checkSum a = go a 0 (sum a)
       where go [] left right = left==right
             go (x:xs) left right = left==right || go xs (left+x) (right-x)
```

at each step you're adding the element to the left value and subtracting from the right, where the initial values are 0 and sum. Terminates when equality reached at any step or when the array is exhausted.

Answer (score 3):

A clever way to think about this: if we need

```
                  x[1] + ... + x[k]  ==  x[k+1] + ... + x[n],
```

then we can add the left-hand side to both sides to get

```
            (x[1] + ... + x[k]) * 2  ==  sum(x).
```

Thus, we can generate all doubled prefix sums, then look for `sum(x)` in them.

```
checkSum :: [Int] -> Bool
checkSum xs = sum xs `elem` doublePrefixSums
    where doublePrefixSums = scanl (\acc x -> acc + 2*x) 0 xs
```

Comment: A clever idea indeed, though be wary about the upper bound of Int. By doubling the prefix sum we halve the range the algorithm works for. Another idea: if the double prefix sum list is ordered then we can exit early – ordering can be guaranteed if the integers are non-negative.

Comment: @erisco, these manipulations are valid mod n, so this transformation does not affect the range for which the algorithm works.  (Though it is a bit subtle...)

Comment: My assumption was that overflow is undefined, but the Haskell 2010 specification says arithmetic is modulo the number of bits to represent the integer ([source](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch18.html#x26-22300018)), so you are correct. Thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using built-in functions.

Use `scanl` and `scanr` to find all the sums from the left and right.

`scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3]` gives you [0, 0+1, 0+1+2, 0+1+2+3]

```
λ> scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
[0,1,3,6]
```

`scanr (+) 0 [1,2,3]` gives you [1+2+3+0, 2+3+0, 3+0, 0]

```
λ> scanr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
[6,5,3,0]
```

Then `zipWith` to identify positions where the lists have equal elements.

```
λ> zipWith (==) [0,1,3,6] [6,5,3,0]
[False,False,True,False]
```

Then `or` to check if this list contains True anywhere.

```
λ> or [False,False,True,False]
True
```

The complete function:

```
checkSum :: [Int] -> Bool
checkSum xs = or (zipWith (==) leftSums rightSums)
  where
    leftSums = scanl (+) 0 xs
    rightSums = scanr (+) 0 xs
```

(This will return True on the empty list.  This seems reasonable to
me, but if you want it to be False you could write a special case for
it or just change `scanr` to `scanr1`.)

Comment: Beautiful! Karakfa's efficient solution uses the fact that `(Int,+)` is a group; you manage it with just the monoid.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question is: for some Int list *x*, determine `∃k::Integer. sum[x₀,…,xₖ] == sum[xₖ,…,xₙ]`. Reasonably, `0 ≤ k < length x` (and `n = length x`) because otherwise *xₖ* is ⊥ and we are not interested in that case.

So how would you prove that proposition? Are we interested in infinite lists? Probably not, so let us assume the list is finite. Then, if the list is finite there are also finite choices for *k* because `0 ≤ k < length x`. A proof then can be done by checking for every choice of *k*. If at least one choice of *k* satisfies the proposition then it is true, and otherwise it is false.

When translating our method to Haskell we want to leverage existing definitions to their fullest. We can just focus on the splits of the list itself, leaving *k* out of the implementation. [luqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521187/260584) beautifully demonstrates this. Be aware that an abstract notation (mathematical, logical, a specification, etc) does not always indicate a good implementation.

Once we know all the splits of the list, we can sum and compare for equality. If at least one comparison succeeds then yield True, otherwise yield False.